# Unable to correctly parse and reassemble binary file using read/writestreams

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary

I'm trying to get certain segments of a binary file and then recombine them into a condensed format.  However, upon completion of this task the binary data is scrambled in a semi-random order.  In fact, the first roughly 15k bytes are correct then conflicts occur continuously after this.  What is going wrong?  I believe that these streams are running into one another (for lack of a better metaphor) and the resultant byte length is correct. Why is this happening?  I thought I was taking adequate precautions as to asynchronicity?

```
                 var destinationPath = something.bin;
                 Promise.all(sources.map(function (source) {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        var output = fs.createWriteStream(destinationPath, {'flags': 'a', 'bufferSize': 64 * 4096});
                        var input = fs.createReadStream(source.filePath, {
                            start: source.parameters.start,
                            end: source.parameters.end + 3
                        });
                        input.on('end', function () {
                            output.on('finish', function () {
                                resolve();
                            });
                        });
                        input.pipe(output);
                    });
                }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this has an impact, but did you try sequentially ? You create many write streams at the same time on the same file.

For example:

```
             var destinationPath = something.bin;
             var promise = Promise.resolve();
             sources.forEach(function (source) {
               promise = promise.then(funtion() {
                 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    var output = fs.createWriteStream(destinationPath, {'flags': 'a', 'bufferSize': 64 * 4096});
                    var input = fs.createReadStream(source.filePath, {
                        start: source.parameters.start,
                        end: source.parameters.end + 3
                    });
                    input.on('end', function () {
                        output.on('finish', function () {
                            resolve();
                        });
                    });
                    input.pipe(output);
                });
              });
            });

            promise.then(function() {
              // we're done here
            });
```

Comment: I don't understand your code.  Wouldn't this execute concurrently?  why Promise.resolve(): outside of the loop and a reassignment of promise inside the loop? Whatre you returning a promise inside the loop to?

Comment: `Promise.all([x1, x2, x3])` (your code) is concurrent, x1, x2, and x3 routines will run at the same time. What the code in my answer ultimately does is `Promise.resolve().then(x1).then(x2).then(x3)`. The `Promise.resolve()` initializes de promise chain, and then every promise is executed only when the previous one is finished.

Comment: Okay thank you I understand that but won't the sources.forEach(){} operate concurrently as well?

Comment: Neither map or forEach are really concurrent, they iterate over an array of values. However the read and write streams, even if started iteratively one after another, get running at the same time very quickly if they dont wait each other. The main point in the code here is not forEach vs map, but Promise.all() vs Promise.then.then.then. The former enable almost-concurrent behaviour, the later enforce a strict sequentiality.